# C: Stop executing and jump to specific point in program on receiving a signal

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I have written a code where two independent programs (say 1 & 2) are communicating via message queues. Each programs sends a message of a specific `mtype` and waits for response of specific `mtype`. Based on the `mtype` functions are invoked. program 2 initially waits on `select()` on the message queue waiting for message chain initiation from program 1 and after each successfull communication chain via message queues comes back to `select()` waiting for program 1's initiation of next communication chain.

I want that program 2 must return to `select()` by stopping execution wherever it was in between a communication chain on receiving a specific signal (say `SIGUUSR1`) from program 1 in case program 1 finds an error in current chain and wants a reset and later would initiate a new communication chain.

On receiving this signal program 2 returns from all functions it is in and straight jumps to `select()`.

I regret for not sharing a code snippet, but I hope I have made my point.

Thanks...

Comment: Use a signal handler where you set a flag that indicates that you need to return to select() step.  The rest of the code can check for this flag and jump accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- When Program 2 starts up, it performs most of the initialization, and then forks a copy of itself.
- The child process creates the socket and connects to it, then selects, and runs as normal.
- When the child process receives `SIGUSR1` it exits with an exit status that indicates a restart is required.
- The parent process just sits waiting for the child to exit, and if the exit status indicates a restart is required, forks another child.  (Any other exit status causes the parent to exit with the same status).

Discussion:

- Restart will be quite slow (need to create sockets etc).
- Process 1 will need to be aware that the message queue will get disconnected when it sends `SIGUSR1`
- This should be very reliable, and portable across Posix.
- The `fork` bit is really only an optimization.  You could make the parent process be some sort of script - in which case the model could even be ported to Windows (obviously the script would be different, but the source of program 2 would be portable).

The only other alternative is to have some sort of flag which Process 2 polls "frequently".  If the flag is set, the process throws an exception (C++), or `longjmp`s (C) back to the `select` call.  The flag is set in the signal handler.

The issue with that approach is that a) it breaks if something happens to stop you polling the flag; b) it is quite hard to write code that is exception safe or which doesn't leak resources if you `longjmp` through it.